# Jmockit: Mock calls in the @Parameters method

Tags: java, junit, parameters, jmockit, expectations

I have a parameterized test class

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
class Tests{
    private int count;
    MyClass object;

   @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {     
             { 0, new MyClass()}
       });
}}
```

Now, there's a call in the MyClass constructor that I want to stub out using non strict expectations. Is it possible to do this?

EDIT:
I've tried @Rogério's suggestion by Adding the following:

```
public static class MockedExternalClass extends MockUp<ExternalClass> {
        public static boolean makeExternalCall() {
            return true;
        }
    }


@BeforeClass
public static void beforeClass() {
    new MockedExternalClass();
}
```

However, the call doesn't get stubbed out and calls the original function anyway.

Comment: You could try applying a `MockUp` from a `@BeforeClass` method, assuming it gets executed before the `@Parameters` method.

Comment: Good idea! Let me try that out. Thank you !

Comment: @Rogério This sadly does not work